# Elasticsearch create snapshot repo throws RepositoryVerificationException

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, nfs

I am trying to take a snapshot for a elasticsearch cluster.The design is the following. There are 3 VMs that run 1 master, 1 data and 1 client node each in Docker containers. Each VM has a volume attached for storing. So a cluster with 3 masters 3 clients 3 data nodes and 3 volumes.

After reading the documentation I created a separate backup volume that I attached to one of the VMs. After that i created a NFS between all 3 VMs that saves the data on the backup volume and then I modified the cluster and mounted the shared NFS directory as a volume to all the nodes in the cluster

So now each VM has the following:

VM1:

```
drwxr-xr-x  16 root   root     3560 Jul 24 10:30 dev
drwxr-xr-x   2 nobody nogroup  4096 Jul 24 11:49 elastic-backup
drwxr-xr-x  97 root   root     4096 Jul 24 14:04 etc
drwxr-xr-x   5 root   root     4096 Apr 27 12:53 home
```

VM2:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root     4096 Jul 24 13:52 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root   root     4096 Jul 24 12:09 boot
drwxr-xr-x   5 root   root     4096 Jan 27 16:41 data
drwxr-xr-x  16 root   root     3580 Jul 24 11:48 dev
drwxr-xr-x   2 nobody nogroup  4096 Jul 24 11:49 elastic-backup
```

VM3:

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 root   root     4096 Jul 24 15:28 boot
drwxr-xr-x   5 root   root     4096 Jan 27 16:41 data
drwxr-xr-x  16 root   root     3560 Jul 24 10:30 dev
drwxr-xr-x   2 nobody nogroup  4096 Jul 24 15:34 elastic-backup
```

When i create a file into it i can see it, modify or whatever and the action is visible from each VM.

Elasticsearch docker nodes:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch   4096 May 15  2018 config
drwxr-xr-x 4 elasticsearch elasticsearch   4096 Jul 23 12:15 data
drwxr-xr-x 2 elasticsearch elasticsearch   4096 Jul 24 15:08 elastic-backup
```

Each docker elasticsearch node has the same directory mounted. I can see all the files from each node.

The problem is that whenever I try to create a snapshot repository i get the following error:

Call:

```
PUT /_snapshot/elastic-backup-1
{
  "type": "fs",
  "settings": {
    "location": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/elastic-backup"
  }
}
```

Error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "repository_verification_exception",
        "reason": "[elastic-backup-1] [[some-id, 'RemoteTransportException[[master-2][VM2-ip][internal:admin/repository/verify]]; nested: RepositoryVerificationException[[elastic-backup-1] a file written by master to the store [/usr/share/elasticsearch/elastic-backup] cannot be accessed on the node [{master-2}{some-id}{some-id}{VM2-ip}{VM2-ip}{zone=AZ2}]. This might indicate that the store [/usr/share/elasticsearch/elastic-backup] is not shared between this node and the master node or that permissions on the store don't allow reading files written by the master node];'], [some-id, 'RemoteTransportException[[data-2][VM2-ip][internal:admin/repository/verify]]; nested: RepositoryVerificationException[[elastic-backup-1] a file written by master to the store [/usr/share/elasticsearch/elastic-backup] cannot be accessed on the node [{data-2}{some-id}{some-id}{VM2-ip}{VM2-ip}{zone=AZ2}]. This might indicate that the store [/usr/share/elasticsearch/elastic-backup] is not shared between this node and the master node or that permissions on the store don't allow reading files written by the master node];'], [some-id, 'RemoteTransportException[[data-1][VM1-ip][internal:admin/repository/verify]]; nested: RepositoryVerificationException[[elastic-backup-1] a file written by master to the store [/usr/share/elasticsearch/elastic-backup] cannot be accessed on the node [{data-1}{some-id}{some-id}{VM1-ip}{VM1-ip}{zone=AZ1}]. This might indicate that the store [/usr/share/elasticsearch/elastic-backup] is not shared between this node and the master node or that permissions on the store don't allow reading files written by the master node];'], [some-id, 'RemoteTransportException[[master-1][VM1-ip][internal:admin/repository/verify]]; nested: RepositoryVerificationException[[elastic-backup-1] a file written by master to the store [/usr/share/elasticsearch/elastic-backup] cannot be accessed on the node [{master-1}{some-id}{some-id}{VM1-ip}{VM1-ip}{zone=AZ1}]. This might indicate that the store [/usr/share/elasticsearch/elastic-backup] is not shared between this node and the master node or that permissions on the store don't allow reading files written by the master node];'], [some-id, 'RemoteTransportException[[data-3][VM3-ip][internal:admin/repository/verify]]; nested: RepositoryVerificationException[[elastic-backup-1] a file written by master to the store [/usr/share/elasticsearch/elastic-backup] cannot be accessed on the node [{data-3}{some-id}{some-id}{VM3-ip}{VM3-ip}{zone=AZ1}]. This might indicate that the store [/usr/share/elasticsearch/elastic-backup] is not shared between this node and the master node or that permissions on the store don't allow reading files written by the master node];']]"
      }
etc ..
```

Anything I am doing wrong ? How can this be fixed

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [Christian_Dahlqvist](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/repository-verification-exception/91105/8), you must provide a shared file system.

> You need to have a shared volume, e.g. a NFS volume, behind the repository path that all nodes can access. This means that if node1 writes a file it will be visible by node 2 and node 3. A directory in the local file system will therefore not work, even if the path is identical on all machines.